# safari web-kit browser page rendering with css

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

I hope this is not a repeated question as I searched it all the web but couldn't figure it out.

I have my website which is ( www.alshakir.com)
I made most of the css external in (mainstyle.css)..

it works fine with all browsers except mobile browers (Apple Ipad /Android tablets) i.e. Safari and web-kit broswers

when I visit the website through them the page is padded with huge amount of space on the left side and the footer ..

when I delete the CSS file (mainstyle.css) .. it works fine even on  the Safari and Webkit ..

So it is a problem of CSS with mobile browsers ..

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Safari Web Inspector, when I delete this code from the `head` of the document, the mass of space on the left disappears:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ct1.addthis.com/static/r07/widget103.css" media="all">
```

Try removing the AddThis widget and code and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: that is perfect @Tom Oakley...Actually the javascript was the reason why my pages are not rendered well on Safari and mobile browsers... Thanks allot

Comment: Glad to hear :) Just a heads up: if a commenter answered your question correctly, it's customary to mark the answer as correct (both to reward the commenter and to let other people know that this question is solved), do this by ticking the tick icon to the left of the question :)